# Múltiples parámetros post angular 2/4/5

Tags: post, http, angular

Estoy trabajando con angular 5 y httpClient, y tengo que enviar 2 objetos por parámetro post pero no se como enviarlos ni como recibirlos.

Los objetos son:

- usuario1 que tiene 3 campos
- usuario2 que tiene 3 campos

Este es el código en mi api web en .net:

```
[HttpPost]
    public bool actualizarUsuario(Usuario oldUser, Usuario newUser)
    {
        try
        {
            return  UsuarioNeg.actualizarUsuario(oldUser, oldUser);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {       
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Y así es como lo estoy enviando desde mi servicio en angular 5:

```
actualizarUsuario(oldUser:any,newUser:any): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.post('www.una-url.com', {'oldUser':oldUser , 'newUser':newUser}, this.header);
}
```

Este es el header:

```
this.header = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', "method": "post" });
```

> **Nota:** Cambie la url por "www.una-url.cl"

Comment: Y ¿cuál es el problema?

Comment: algo debo estar haciendo mal 
me aparece este problema que dejare en este enlace https://i.gyazo.com/455546def6788e465788eda972060a8a.png

Answer (score 1):

A mi parecer te falta decir exactamente cual es el problema...
En primera instancia para enviar datos por *POST* con `"Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` no se puede enviar JSON como lo estas realizando en el código anterior.

Para `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` el cuerpo del mensaje HTTP enviado al servidor es esencialmente un *string* enorme; "Los valores son codificados en tuplas de valores llaves separados por '&', con un '='  entre la llave y el valor." [Mas Detalles.](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST)

Entonces primero debes codificar to JSON en un formato valido de `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`.

```
{'oldUser':oldUser , 'newUser':newUser}
```